# How to determine which subclass to be created?

Tags: java

In common way, we may check the input to determine which subclass to be created outside the constructor.

In this example, we check it in the main function :

```
class Fruit 
{
    String name;
    Fruit(String name) 
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

class Apple extends Fruit 
{
    Apple(String name) 
    {
        super(name);
    }
}

class Orange extends Fruit 
{
    Orange(String name) 
    {
        super(name);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String input = ""; // apple or orange
    if(input.equals("Apple"))
        Fruit f = new Apple("apple");   
    else if (input.equals("Orange"))
        Fruit f = new Orange("orange");
}
```

How can we check it inside the constructor to new a specific subclass like that?

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Fruit f = new Fruit("apple");
}

abstract class Fruit 
{
    String name;
    Fruit(String name) 
    {
        if(name.equals("Apple"))
            this = new Apple("apple");  
        else if (name.equals("Orange"))
            this = new Orange("orange");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was actually reading a book called [Effective Java](http://books.google.com.au/books/about/Effective_Java.html?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&redir_esc=y) the other night and this sort of problem was discussed. What you might want to take a look into is the [Factory method pattern](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). For this you might have a situation like the following:

```
public class Fruit {
    ...
    public static Fruit createFruit(String name) {
        if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("apple"))
            return new Apple();
        if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("orange"))
            return new Orange();
        ...
        return new Fruit(name);
    }
    ...
}
```

Then, when creating a new fruit, use this instead:

```
Fruit apple = Fruit.createFruit("apple"); //returns an apple instance
Fruit orange = Fruit.createFruit("orange"); //returns an orange instance
Fruit fruit = Fruit.createFruit("watermelon"); //returns a basic fruit instance with watermelon as the name
```

Edit: Changed the naming scheme to reflect the true purpose of the factory method; thanks to Bartlomiej Lewandowski for that.

Comment: Really close, you should change the function name to createFruit as  you really are creating new instances of Fruit

Answer (score 3):

First of all, don't use `==` for String comparison. Use `equals`.

Second of all, you can't decide in the constructor of the super-class the sub-class you wish to create an instance of. When you call `new Fruit(...)`, you create an instance of the super-class, which won't pass compilation in your case, since `Fruit` is abstract. Even if it wasn't abstract, you can't assign anything to `this`. You can't change the type of the class you are instantiating.